# Cylindrical shells method

Tags: calculus

I am really struggling with this cylindrical shells problem. I really do struggle with the rotating around the $y$-axis.

> Find the volume of the solid that results by revolving the region enclosed by the curves
>   $y=4x$, $x=1$, $x=4$, and $y=0$
>   about the $y$-axis. (Round your answer to 3 decimal places).

I tried integrating from $1$ to $4$ using $y/4$ as the height and $1+y$ as the radius but I just cant seem to get it can anyone offer me any help with this?

Comment: Take x as the radius, not (1+y)

Answer (score 1):

If you are rotating about the $y$-axis, the distance to the $y$-axis is $x.$

the height is $4x$

$2\pi \int_1^4 (x)(4x) dx$

As you are trying to integrate this problem with respect to y, it suggests that you don't have a very good picture in your mind of what you are trying to do.

I suggest you make some sketches.  The region before you rotate it.  The 3d shape and a typical shell.  This will give you some intuition, and it is easier to fit the math to a good model then to calculate away without one.